# pass a template with N parameters, as a template parameter, specified with N-1 parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I have template class `A1` which takes a template template parameter `T`.

Also, I have a class, like `A2` which not satisfy template template parameter of `A1`, but with help of `using` can satisfy it.

So, the question is, can I inline apply an adapted `A2` to `A1`? I mean something like commented out lines.

As you can see, it is not crucial, because I already handle it, but I just ask.

```
template<template<int A, char B> typename T>
class A1 /* : public T<5, 'a'> */ {};

template<int A, char B, bool C> class A2{};

template<int A, char B, typename D> class A4{};

template<int A, char B>
using A3 = A2<A, B, true>;


template<int A, char B, bool C = true> class A5{};


int main()
{
    A1<A3> a;
    A1<A5> b;

    // Avoid name pollution (or other reason)
//  A1<A2<_,_,false>> c;
//  A1<A4<_,_,int>> d;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would be fine with writing this:

```
A1< Add_true<A2>::type > c;
```

Then you are almost there:

> ```
> template<int A, char B>
> using A3 = A2<A, B, true>;
> ```

Instead of writing the template explicitly you can write a template that "uses" the desired template:

```
template< template <int A,char B,bool> typename T>
struct Add_true {
    template <int A,char B> using type = T<A,B,true>;
};
```

[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9j2T9LlEycKzB0o2)

I think it should be straightforward to turn that into a `Add_bool` that lets you add either `true` or `false`. I never experimented with variadic template template parameters, but I think it would be fun to extend this to "bind" arbitrary template parameters.

**PS** It never occured to me that binding template parameters is that simple. Thank you for the question :)

**PPS** If your question was actually to bind `true` without any other helper type / function, then to my knowledge that is not possible.