# How to transform template to template pre C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++03, template-templates

Triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60309270/4117728) I wrote a template that allows to transform a template into a template with different parameters:

```
template< template <int A,char B,bool> typename T>
struct Add_true {
    template <int A,char B> using type = T<A,B,true>;
};
```

Background: The aim was to pass a `template<int A, char B, bool C> class A2{};` as template template parameter to a `template<template<int A, char B> typename T> class A1 {};`. I learned about templates with C++11. It was quite a shift in thinking about code once I got used to writing types/functions that take types and "return" types instead of writing functions that take values and return values. It never occurred to me that it is also surprisingly simple to write templates that given a template "return" a different template. The thing is I have not the slightest clue how to write the above or similar without alias templates that are only available since C++11. What was possible always afaik is the following. Given

```
template <int A,char B, bool C> struct Foo{};
```

I can "bind" a bool parameter to `Foo` via:

```
template <int A,char B>
struct Add_true_to_Foo {
     typedef Foo<A,B> type;
};
```

But now `Add_true_to_Foo<A,B>::type` is not a template and I have not the slightest clue without C++11 how to write a `Add_true` that would not only work for `Foo` but also for

```
template <int A,char B, bool C> struct Bar{};
```

Maybe I am missing something obvious. My quesiton is

**Is it possible to write an equivalent to the above `Add_true` before C++11?**

Answer (score 2):

There are no strict equivalents of the C++11 template using,
but you can add extra template class instead to mimic behavior and with different syntax:

```
template <template <int, char, bool> class C>
struct Add_true {
    template <int A, char B>
    struct apply
    {
        typedef T<A, B, true> type;
    }
};
```

With usage:

```
template <int A,char B, bool C> struct Foo{};

typedef Add_true<Foo>::apply<42, '*'>::type my_type; // Foo<42, '*', true>
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand this answer. Can I use this as parameter for a `template<template<int A, char B> typename T> class A1 {};`? I dont see that, but anyhow I will have to spend some time one this and in any case, thanks for the answer

Comment: ok I think I got it. In `A1` I would have to use `T::type`, but if possible I would like to avoid that. Sorry if the questions wasnt clear enough

Comment: Answer from StoryTeller - Unslander Monica would have the syntax you want (-> template type), with the caveats that the type is not exactly what you want (but derives from the one you want) to be usable directly in `A1`. My solution indeed require to change `A1` with extra `typename /*..*/::type`.

Comment: so the answer to the question i didnt ask directly, "did alias templates bring something substantially new to c++ templates", is "yes". I am still amazed, I mean the techniques applied here arent completely new to me, but the question I linked made me see things from a completely new perspective

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance would be the C++03 way

```
template< template <int A,char B,bool> typename T>
struct Add_true {
    template <int A,char B>
    struct type : T<A,B,true> {};
};
```

In both C++11 and C++03, `type` is the name of a new template. The difference is only is only in what the specializations mean. For alias templates, they stand exactly for the thing being aliased, while here they are new types. However, derived to base conversions should allow treating the C++03 `type` specialization almost exactly as if they were the thing they "alias".

Comment: I'm not a fan of the inheritance there... There's no easy way to retrieve `T<A, B, true>` on its own.

Comment: @Quentin - Yeah, that's why alias templates were introduced and are superior. But if you are limited to C++03 and your goal is to create a new template (and not say, do something like `std::allocator::rebind`). Then this is it.

Comment: thanks, I will have to spend some time on this before I can accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 we didn't have template aliases, but the same could be achieved with structure templates like this:

```
template<template<int A, char B> class T> class A1
{
    typedef typename T<1, 'a'>::type actual_A2;
};

template<int A, char B, bool C> class A2 {};

template< template<int A, char B, bool C> class T >
struct Add_true
{
    template<int A, char B>
    struct apply
    {
        typedef T<A, B, true> type;
    };
};
typedef Add_true<A2> A2_with_true;

A1< A2_with_true::apply > a1;
```

Note that you need to change how `A1` works as it must use a nested `type` typedef to obtain the actual `A2` specialization.

Comment: sorry but your "simplification" goes in the wrong direction. If you read the Q&A I linked, your `A2_with_true` is what OP had in the question and also your C++03 solution isnt exactly what I was looking for, because your `A2_with_true` only binds `true` to `A2`  but to do the same for `Foo` or `Bar` I would have to write a `Foo_with_true` and `Bar_with_true`, which is exactly what is to be avoided

Comment: That wasn't clear from the question, but I updated the answer to define `Add_true`.

Comment: I had the same doubt on a different question. Now the parameter you pass to `A1` isnt the type itself but inside `A1` I would have to use `T::type` to get the desired type, no?